# Images are not displaying after hosting on IIS 7.5

Tags: html

Images are displaying perfectly fine when running the website from visual studio 2013.

But after publish and host the code on IIS images doesn't show up.

HTML

```
<img src="../../../Content/images/1l.jpg" height="67" title="Step 1" width="67" style="margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 5px;" />
```

Website is in angularjs. Is there any way to make changes in src so that images can pick the path correctly ?

Comment: Depending on your directory structure, most probably the src="../../../Content/images/1l.jpg" is an invalid relative path when hosted on IIS. Inspect the element in the browser to see what the relative path should be or try src="/Content/images/1l.jpg" if you're not sure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check in iis->mime type of jpg (image/jpg).
2. Try to load the image in different tab of the browser and just play with the path (remove ../ and add). You can see it also in fiddler to check where it is trying to load your image.